# How to set highchart boxplot size

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am making a box plot in highchart, that can show between 1 and 6 objects.  Unfortunately, high chart scales the size width the number of objects, so while my chart looks good when there are 6 objects it looks really bad when there are only 1 or 2 because the box plot ends up being too big and stretched horizontally.  Is there a way to fix the size so that the boxes look the same regardless of the number of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `maxPointWidth` or `pointWidth` option to control the box plot width.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    type: 'boxplot',
    maxPointWidth: 50,
    data: [
      [760, 801, 848, 895, 965]
    ]
  }]
});
```

**Demo:**

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w86xv14d/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.boxplot.maxPointWidth
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.boxplot.pointWidth